# Add new column in google sheet using C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a new column in google sheet using c# and my code doesn't work, it's possible?

This is my code:

```
// Addind new column (not working! in sheet I have one column only)  
var newColumnIndex = 2;   CellQuery cellQuery = new
CellQuery(worksheet.CellFeedLink);   
var cellFeed =
service.Query(cellQuery);   
service.Insert(cellFeed, new CellEntry(1,
newColumnIndex, "test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do this:

```
worksheet.Cols = worksheet.Cols + 1;

worksheet.Update();

worksheet.Rows = worksheet.Rows + 1;

worksheet.Update();
```

Where worksheet is a WorksheetEntry.